# My c++ codes doesn't create or edit text file

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I searched this problem on web and I found some solutions but they didn't solve. So I must ask to someone. My problem is about c++, I am writing normal code but any file operations command doesn't work, they don't create or change text files. After It work, doesn't create a text file on same directory I tried to change my ide, I tried to run as Admin, I tried to open show secret folders, I tried to change compiler's bit, I tried to run on D:, I turned off my anti-virus app but they didn't solve. I added system("dir") the end of the codes and it showed to me the text file(i couldn't see in the folder again) but after this, I went to same directory with cmd(as admin) but this time i couldn't see the text. I couldn't remember what i've tried more. Also I have some problems about permissions i don't know maybe this about the my problem. Here is a part of my codes;

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    void adding() {
        string userName;
        cout << "Enter your nickname: ";
        cin >> userName;
        ofstream userFile;
        userFile.open("users.txt", ios::app);
        userFile<< userName;
        userFile.close();
        cout<<"The user is succesfully added!"<<endl;
    }

int main()
{
    cout<<system("cd");
    adding();
    system("dir");
}
```

Comment: Set in your IDE the "working directory" which may be or may be not the same as the current directory where the executable can be found.

Comment: There nothing wrong with your code. You just need to adjust your IDE so that it sets the working directory to be what you are expecting it to be,

Comment: Also output of "cout<<system("cd");" gave me a "0" after the directory in next line.

Comment: "Also output of "cout<<system("cd");" gave me a "0" after the directory in next line." because `system` returns the return value. In this case, zero, indicating success.

Comment: Try resetting the IDE configuration. The code seems to be working fine.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say my IDE, I am using Dev C++. I couldn't find where i can change working directory but I reset settings from environment options/directories. ( https://imgur.com/a/ZUETniw )  Still there isn't a text file.

Comment: and I guess it was true because there i couldn't find another similiar thing.

Comment: Maybe try call flush before close also try to print cwd so tha you know where the file is stored.